# How to make dynamically Tree View with input in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I'm looking to add contents like division, input text, button... in a tree structure in a web app. I was hoping to use Angular for this task.

HTML:

```
<script type="text/ng-template"  id="tree_item_renderer.html">
    {{data.name}}
    <button ng-click="add(data)">Add node</button>
    <button ng-click="delete(data)" ng-show="data.nodes.length > 0">Delete nodes</button>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="data in data.nodes" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'"></li>
    </ul>
</script>

<ul ng-app="Application" ng-controller="TreeController">
    <li ng-repeat="data in tree" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'"></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
angular.module("myApp", []).
controller("TreeController", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.delete = function(data) {
        data.nodes = [];
    };
    $scope.add = function(data) {
        var post = data.nodes.length + 1;
        var newName = data.name + '-' + post;
        data.nodes.push({name: newName,nodes: []});
    };
    $scope.tree = [{name: "Node", nodes: []}];
}]);
```

Have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brendanowen/uXbn6/8/)

This picture below show you what I hope to attain!
[image]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: There is a directive called Treemodel which can solve your issue with minor tweaking.

Comment: @RutwickGangurde Can you plz give me an exemple

Comment: @TonyBarnes here is the picture http://i.stack.imgur.com/GQTaV.jpg

Comment: @PavelHoral http://i.stack.imgur.com/GQTaV.jpg

Comment: @Bouhirmani Here: http://jsfiddle.net/eu81273/8LWUc/18/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to creat nested divisions with AngularJs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29663082/how-to-creat-nested-divisions-with-angularjs)

Comment: @PavelHoral, yes,it's my post :)

Comment: Seems like you have asked pretty much the same question 3 times. I consider that spamming SO. Also I still don't understand what the question is.

Comment: @RutwickGangurde yes, but i  want to add firlds dynamically, and infinitly.

Comment: Try to play around with that example. I'm sure you'll manage to get what you want.

Comment: @PavelHoral, i'm sorry for duplcating my post,I want to add fields which contain button and input text etc.... dynamically in my tree

Comment: @RutwickGangurde, i want to add  fields which contain button and input text etc.... I'm trying with ng-bind-html but my input disapear :/